# Regex boost library comparing

Tags: c++, regex, boost

```
int array[328];
string array2[328];
int array3[328]; //counter array
int value=0;

std::string text("((1 0) (25 5) (27 2) )((25 5) (27 2) (31 2) )");
boost::regex regex("(\\d)+[^\\d+\\)]"); // [^\\d+] ");


boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(), regex, 0);
boost::sregex_token_iterator end;


for( ; iter != end; ++iter )
{
    std::cout<<*iter<<"\n";


    for(int b=0; b<328; b++)
      {
        if(*iter == "1")
          {
            cout << "yes\n";
            array3[b] = array3[b]+ count;
            break;
          }
      }
}

return 0;}
```

We are using the boost library to make regular expressions to see how many times the 1, 25 27 and 31 appears in other words just the fist numbers after the parenthesis. HOwever, we are trying to use an array with the numbers between 1-28 to compare it but we dont know the type of iter to compare if that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure this is the reason, but you can't compare char array strings in C++ using `==`. `== "1"` makes me think you are doing trying to do this.  You have to use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What result do you expect the above code to output?

Comment: Please don't simply post a huge block of code and expect us to figure out what you're trying to do, what's going wrong, and how to fix it. What are you trying to achieve? What *specific* step is giving you trouble? What have you tried? Which lines do you think are incorrect?

Comment: We are trying to count how many times the 1 25 27 and 31 appears. The one is a means by which we test it. Bot sure if we should have used string or int or anything else

Comment: if anything it is the if statement that is the problem

Comment: @Cornelius - We can try to help you, but please trim down the code to a few relevant lines and describe the problem as well as you can. It will help if you suggest some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: The code was better in its original form.  Leave it in a fully-contained `main` block; just get rid of everything that isnt directly related to the regex matching.  Your code should be complete and minimal.

Comment: @Merlyn - `*iter` returns (a reference to?) a `sub_match` object which has **lots** of `operator==` overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Both your code and your regex are malformed badly in numerous ways.  But beyond this, the fundamental problem you are having is that given how your regex is formed, the match will result in a `pair` of `string::const_iterator`s, pointing to the beginning and one-past-the-end of the match, respectively.

Change your code to:

```
    for(int b=0; b<328; b++)
      {
        if(*iter == "1 ")
          {
            cout << "yes\n";
            array3[b] = array3[b]+ count;
            break;
          }
      }
}
```

...and it will work.